# Why can't my Gitlab pipeline find python packages installed in Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, gitlab

My file structure is as follows:

- `Dockerfile`
- `.gitlab-ci.yml`

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install make
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install pygdbmi
RUN pip3 install pyyaml
RUN pip3 install Path
```

And here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
test-job:
  stage: test
  image: runners:test-harness
  script:
    - cd test-harness
    # - pip3 install pygdbmi
    # - pip3 install pyyaml
    - python3 main.py
  artifacts:
    untracked: false
    when: on_success
    expire_in: "30 days"
    paths:
      - test-harness/script.log
```

For some reason the `pip3 install` in the Dockerfile doesn't seem to be working as I get the error:

```
python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/builds/username/test-harness/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pygdbmi.gdbcontroller import GdbController
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygdbmi'
```

When I uncomment the two commented lines in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
# - pip3 install pygdbmi
# - pip3 install pyyaml
```

It works fine but ideally, I want those 2 packages to be installed in the `Dockerfile` not the `.gitlab-ci.yml` pipeline stage

I've tried changing the `WORKDIR` as well as `USER` and it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any ideas/solutions?

Comment: Why are you not using a requirements.txt file? anyway, I don't see `pip3 install pygdbmi` in the `DockerFile` you pasted?

Comment: Can you check the image you have built above. Drop a shell and try to execute the file. Check if thats working.

Comment: @Axeltherabbit I tried with and without a requirements.txt file, neither worked. As for the `pip3 install pygdbmi`, I simply forgot to add it in the question, I've added it now, sorry about that.

Comment: @HarshitRuwali I've checked the image I built above and typed: `pip3 list` and it shows 3 packages but not the ones I've installed: 
`# pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.3.1
setuptools 65.5.1
wheel      0.38.4`
So after executing it in a shell it simply tells me what I already know, which is that those python packages aren't being installed.

Comment: I built the image with the above Dockerfile and for me packages are getting installed. Nothing seems wrong. 
`docker run -it ca2b49d39561 /bin/bash
root@65260a280f6e:/# pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- --------
path       16.6.0
pip        23.0
pygdbmi    0.11.0.0
PyYAML     6.0
setuptools 65.5.1
wheel      0.38.4
root@65260a280f6e:/`

Comment: Thanks for that, I added the `/bin/bash` as well and that works for the dockerfile locally but it still doesn't work for the gitlab pipeline unfortunately, any ideas for why the pipeline isn't finding those packages?